# RatingBar cuts off progressDrawable

Tags: android, ratingbar

The `RatingBar` cuts of my `progressDrawable`, no matter how I set it's height (`wrap_content`, exact `Drawable`'s height do not work). It seems, that the RatingBar does not play well with non square images. Any ideas how to avoid the clipping? The image do have some transparent padding, the size is hinted with blue border in the screenshot.

```
<RatingBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:numStars="1"
                   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/selector_person_bar"
                   android:rating="0"
                   android:stepSize="1"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it, due to a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63428111) in the implementation of the `ProgressBar`, `android:maxHeight` has to be set to avoid clipping.